# In meteor.js is it possible to re-start a stopped a subscription?

Tags: meteor

For example:

```
var subscription = Meteor.subscribe("allplayers");

//later

subscription.stop();

//later

subscription.start();
```

I know start() doesn't exist, because I've tried.  Is there a different way?

Answer (score 11):

Simply resubscribing to the publication restarts the subscription.

```
var subscription = Meteor.subscribe("allplayers");

//later - stop subscription

subscription.stop();

//later - restart subscription

subscription = Meteor.subscribe("allplayers");
```